# Unexplained drilling/vibrating/sounds like cell phone sound in wall!

Tags: wiring, phone-wiring, vibration

my family is at their wits end. Every single Monday, Thurs and Fri morning between 6am-7:30am we hear from the upstairs bedroom wall/ceiling a vibrating or drilling sound that lasts like 2-5 seconds. It also sounds like a cell phone vibrating on a glass table. We live in a semi and asked our neighbours and they don't hear it and don't have an alarm. I think it's an alarm because it happens at perfect times like 6:15, 7:30. but we don't hear it ANY other time. It's driving us crazy and waking all of us up every morning it happens. Please help me, what is this horrible sound?

Comment: Some practical joker left an alarm clock in the attic or hidden someplace else in the property??

Comment: Before I jump to conclusions, what is a "semi"?

Comment: @isherwood  I think that's Canadian for "duplex".  They call them "semi-detached" or just "semi".

Comment: @jwh20 thank you for this, had no idea they weren't called semi-detached outside of Canada, and I hope it isn't that, been living here for 7 years and the sound started this March :|

Comment: @kayjay  In the US, it's almost always "duplex" but I believe some of the northern states that border Canada have some that call them "semi-detached".  So there has been NO opportunity since March for a "friend" to have planted something?

Comment: Welcome to [diy.se]. I don't think this is going to be possible for us to answer, but I'd suggest that you set your own alarm  to get up before this goes off and go to where you _think_ it is, then listen. Touch a wall, put your ear to the floor, recruit the rest of the family to do the same. Once you've at least located a room, you can start zeroing in on a specific location. You may also want to look out the windows to see if there's a specific vehicle going by that's making the sound. Beyond some sleuthing tips, I don't think we can help you...

Comment: @jwh20 no one has been in since March because of COVID. It's so strange for it to just start up out of no where. Not sure if it's related to the metre hookup that's on that wall outside to the hydro line, but not sure it would ring off on a timed schedule.

Comment: @FreeMan thank you for your answer and your welcoming. We've had family members sleep in different rooms and floors to ID where it's coming from, and we know that it's in the master bedroom from it sounds like the corner of the wall where it meets the ceiling. We haven't put our ears the wall to see how much it's vibrating, so that can be our next steps.

Comment: So there is a meter on the outside of the wall where the sound seems to come from?  Is it an electronic meter?

Comment: Might check with the local utilities if they have any polling of customers' meters that takes place on your "alarm" schedule.

Comment: @jwh20 yeah right outside that wall is the connection for the main hydro pole that then runs down the house into the electronic hydro metre. I don't think the metre itself is the problem, but it could be that connection on the outside of the bedroom wall. Not sure again if there's polling of metres on a schedule but can investigate with them. Thanks for all your suggestions!

Comment: @DJohnM That's a good idea, I thought it would be implausible that they would poll metres on a schedule and that it would vibrate so loudly into our house - especially since this only started in April after living here for years, but who knows what the hydro company's schedules are.